# How to do this query with mysql join?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Hi im trying to make a left join on this database.

Table category:

```
// `category` table has 3 columns 
id,business_id (FK from business),category.
```

Table business:

```
// `business` table has 12 columns
id, name, etc (all info for that business)
```

**What I need** is to filter all the business that are Restaurants and join it to the respective business ID.

Problem is that each business have multiple category and when I do a select/join the result doesnt return DISTINCT businesses.

Here is one of the query i tried:

```
SELECT category.category,business.* 
FROM category 
INNER JOIN business 
ON category.business_id = business.id;
```

I also tried **left**, **right** joins. But my pc is either taking forever or not working.
P.S the dataset is 8.6G
![database output]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Begyd.png

Comment: So, if you only want distinct business, why do you need to join it to category table?

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks okay, but it is lacking that you are only looking for restaurants.  However, firstly, I would make sure I have an index built on category.id

```
create index your_index_name on your_table_name(your_column_name);
```

Then you can simplify your query this way:

```
select a.id, a.category, b.* from category a left join business b on a.business_id=b.id WHERE a.category='Restaurants';
```

Even with that, a table that's 8.6G is going to take time.  Since you said "pc" instead of "server" it might take a long time.

Comment: Thank for the answer, im still a new account so cant give you a upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM Business b
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Category
    WHERE category = 'Restaurants' AND business_id = b.id
)
```

Comment: This also worked but i need the extra column, that is why i asked for a JOIN. But this also gave me the correct output!